# Multiple dynamic instances of bootstrap-timepicker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I am using the bootstrap-timepicker for rails and I am using it in a form helper. It works very well if there is only one instance of it. Here is a code fragment:

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker input-append span2 offset0">
  <%= f.label :to_hour %>
  <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small" value='12:15 PM'>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>
```

However it doesn't work when there are multiple instances of it in a single page. Essentially I have multiple dynamic rows of data that require a time picker each and the examples that I have found were simple and had a unique input id and corresponding javascript.

Does anyone know how I can make this dynamic or know of any examples that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an ID at all. Use a class:

```
<input type="text" class="input-small timepicker" value='12:15 PM'>
```

And in your JS:

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker(...);
```