# Appending Bootstrap Timepicker using js doesn't run the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap timepicker with dynamic multiple instances.
I am able to create the instances but for some reason only the first instance is showing the timepicker, rest all are just appearing as text fields.
i am using a class to call the timepicker and not an ID.

This is the HTML code-

```
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                       <font>from</font>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-small timepicker">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <font>to</font>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-small timepicker">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <button type="button" id="addslots" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                </td></tr>
                        </table>
```

This is the script-

```
$('#addslots').click(function () {
     var table = $(this).closest('table');
     console.log(table.find('input:text').length);
     if (table.find('.row').length < 7) {
         var x = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr');
         $.each(x, function (i,val) {
             val.remove();
         });
         table.append("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-1'>from</div><div class='col-md-3'><div class='input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker'><input type='text' class='form-control timepicker'></div></div><div class='col-md-1'>to</div><div class='col-md-3'><div class='input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker'><input type='text' class='form-control  timepicker'></div></div><br><br>");
         $.each(x, function (i, val) {
             table.append(val);
         });
     }
    });
```

There is a similar question [Multiple dynamic instances of bootstrap-timepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807554/multiple-dynamic-instances-of-bootstrap-timepicker) , but i hav already done what the answer suggested

Comment: can you create jsFiddle for the same ?

Comment: You will also need the jquery-ui css and js for timepicker, if its not present.

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lrxj4umo/

Answer (score 0):

Because of the first $.each loop all elements from the DOM will be removed, So, whatever the binding tho those elements will not work. So, the best is try to bind timepicker after second $.each loop

Comment: Let me have the code where you are binding the timepicker. So, That I can answer